# UWP Background Task - Application Trigger - Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Tags: uwp, background-process, background-task

In UWP I'm trying to create a simple background task on demand. So when I click a button, I want a background task to kick off and process some files in the background.

Below is what my basic Task code is:

```
public class BackgroundSyncService
{
    private ApplicationTrigger trigger = new ApplicationTrigger();

    public async Task Start()
    {
        if (IsRegistered())
            Deregister();

        BackgroundExecutionManager.RemoveAccess();

        // does this prompt everytime?
        await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();

        var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();

        builder.Name = "BackgroundTask";
        builder.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(BackgroundTask).FullName;

        builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
        BackgroundTaskRegistration task = builder.Register();

        task.Completed += Task_Completed;

        var result = await trigger.RequestAsync();
    }

    private void Task_Completed(BackgroundTaskRegistration sender, BackgroundTaskCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        // alert UI
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Deregister();
    }

    private void Deregister()
    {
        var taskName = "BackgroundTask";

        foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            if (task.Value.Name == taskName)
                task.Value.Unregister(true);
    }

    private bool IsRegistered()
    {
        var taskName = "BackgroundTask";

        foreach (var task in BackgroundTaskRegistration.AllTasks)
            if (task.Value.Name == taskName)
                return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

When the code hits `builder.Register()` it throws the following exception:

> System.Exception: 'Cannot create a file when that file already exists.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B7)'

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here or what this error means in context of a Background Task?

Answer (score -1):

For your issue, it is because you have a file with the specified name already exists in the current folder when you create the file. You can try to specify the [NameCollisionOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.namecollisionoption) when you create the file.

```
var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.
    CreateFileAsync("MyFile", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
```

As your code in your example project, you have used the [ApplicationData.LocalSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalSettings), when you add the setting key, you should check whether the key is existing.

```
var settings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
if (!settings.Values.ContainsKey("BackgroundTask"))
{
    settings.Values.Add("BackgroundTask", "Hello from UWP");
}
```

Or you can use the [ApplicationData.LocalSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData#Windows_Storage_ApplicationData_LocalSettings) as following to use the key and change its value,

```
var settings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
settings.Values["BackgroundTask"] = "Hello from UWP";
```

You can also look into the [Store and retrieve settings and other app data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data) topic.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I'm seeing this behavior even after uninstall the UWP app completely and having VS redeploy. This is a Xamarin Forms app if that matters. It does skip over the "IsRegistered" call so it's definitely not registered on first load of a fresh app.

Comment: I can not reproduce this issue in my side. I used the scenario in my answer, I will not get the error again. Could you provide a minimum sample to help me see your issue?

Comment: @aherrick I have modified my answer above, you can see it and have a try.

Comment: I don't follow are you talking about this code? https://github.com/aherrick/XFormsOfflineSync/blob/master/XFormsOfflineSync.UWP.Background/BackgroundTask.cs I have that code commented out

Comment: But if I run your project directly without any change, it works well in my side, there are no any error happens.

Comment: Hmm I’ve rebuilt the project locally and changed the name of he background task itself. What more do I need to do to clear out or update so it’s not attempting to write to file?

Comment: In the backgound task here , there is nothing to create or write to the file, 
https://github.com/aherrick/XFormsOfflineSync/blob/master/XFormsOfflineSync.UWP.Background/BackgroundTask.cs, and your app works well in my side, so I can not reproduce the issue if there is no any file created or written in the background task. It is so odd that we have the same project but get different result. You can try to clean and rebuild your project,even restart your device to test it again.

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with files or folders.
I stumbled at this error when you're trying to register the ApplicationTrigger on multiple BackgroundTaskBuilder. The error you get is misleading.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using ApplicationTrigger for the BackgroundTask registration, and creating a new instance of ApplicationTrigger before re-registering fixed this error for me.