BackgroundTaskBuilder.Register throws HRESULT: 0x00700B7 on multiple task registration
My app is attempting to register two separate background tasks.  The first task registration succeeds.  The attempt to register the second task results in an exception with the following text:
Cannot create a file when that file already exists. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700B7)
There is this question, but I am not reusing ApplicationTrigger instances across registrations; each task gets its own.
Also, the first (successfully-registered) task's Run method is never called, before or after a call to its trigger's RequestAsync method (which returns Allowed).
The two tasks are registered in the appxmanifest:
<Package>
[ ... ]
 <Extensions>
  <Extension Category="windows.activatableClass.inProcessServer">
   <InProcessServer>
    <Path>UI.exe</Path>
    <ActivatableClass ThreadingModel="MTA" ActivatableClassId="BackgroundTasks.BackgroundTaskOne" />
    <ActivatableClass ThreadingModel="MTA" ActivatableClassId="BackgroundTasks.BackgroundTaskTwo" />
   </InProcessServer>
  </Extension>
 </Extensions>
[ ... ]
 <Applications>
  <Application Id="App" [...] >
   [...]
   <Extensions>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="BackgroundTasks.BackgroundTaskOne">
     <BackgroundTasks>
      <Task Type="general" />
     </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
    <Extension Category="windows.backgroundTasks" EntryPoint="BackgroundTasks.BackgroundTaskTwo">
     <BackgroundTasks>
      <Task Type="general" />
     </BackgroundTasks>
    </Extension>
   </Extensions>    
  </Application>
 </Applications>
</Package>

Note that I openly do not understand ThreadingModel very well.  I also tried STA and both, the other options suggested by Intellisense, and the behavior didn't change.
Each task class has the following signature (e.g.):
public sealed class BackgroundTaskOne : IBackgroundTask 

and uses identical code to attempt the registration:
var requestTask = BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync().AsTask();
requestTask.Wait();
var builder = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
builder.Name = GetType().Name;
builder.TaskEntryPoint = GetType().FullName;
// builder.IsNetworkRequested = true;
builder.SetTrigger(trigger);
try {
    registration = builder.Register();
    return true;
} catch(Exception ex) {
    Log.Logger.Error($"BackgroundTaskBuilder.Register: {ex.Message}");
    Log.Logger.Information($"Name: {builder.Name}");
    Log.Logger.Information($"TaskEntryPoint: {builder.TaskEntryPoint}");
    return false;
}

I've uploaded an MCRE here.  Click buttons, see errors in the debug console.
Apparently I don't understand what constitutes uniqueness in a background task registration; I would've presumed the combination of Name and perhaps TaskEntryPoint would serve to uniquely identify a background task.  The exception, however, seems to suggest I'm trying to do the same thing twice.
Questions:

Should an app be able to register more than one BackgroundTask?
If so, what do I have wrong such that I get this exception?
Why doesn't the Run method on either task ever get called?


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50126390/uwp-background-task-application-trigger-cannot-create-a-file-when-that-file

@HansPassant Yes, a similar question has been asked.  However, I submit that my situation (attempting to register multiple background tasks) is different enough to stand separately.  I'll edit my question to mention that the one relevant answer to the linked question is not useful in my situation.

UWP apps support multiple background tasks. I could run my sample with two background tasks correctly, both of them are triggered by system trigger like timer. I'd suggest you double check the TaskEntryPoint to see if that is correct.

@RoyLi-MSFT Thanks for your input.  I did check TaskEntryPoint and verified that it's correct in each case.  It couldn't not be, as it's dynamically filled in with GetType().FullName -- but I did set breakpoints and double-check.

I noticed that you are adding InProcessServer in your app which is not a normal background task. Could you please tell me more details about your background task?

@RoyLi-MSFT Thanks for engaging.  I edited the question to include a reproducible example.  Rather than clutter the comments section with a lot of back-and-forth, please refer to that example code if you have time to do so.  If you know of a good place for a longer discussion, please let me know as well.

I can't open your sample on my side. It's better to update your information in your question.

@RoyLi-MSFT - What more information do you need about my background task?  All the relevant information (AFAIK) regarding registration is already in the question.

@BrianA.Henning Your question is the only google result for this problem. Any luck figuring it out? Or did you resort to using a single background task with parameters?

@BiffMaGriff - Not yet.  I don't have a lot of time to devote to this project...I think when I get back to it, I'm going to refactor it so that there's only one background task.
